# Spring Boot get spring.profiles.active value in a static block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

Is it possible to get the value of the spring active profile in some class's static block?

I have tried `@value("$(spring.profiles.active)")` and `@Autowired Environment env;` to get the value but both resulted as null inside the static block.

I understand that the static block is executed before spring initialization during bean loading, So is there any workaround to get active profile value or any value from application.yml inside the static block?

Sample Code:

```
@Value("$(spring.profiles.active)")
private String env;

static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            ClassPathResource wsdlLoc = new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/Transaction_"+env+".wsdl");
            url = new URL(wsdlLoc.getURL().toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        TRANSACTIONPROCESSOR_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        TRANSACTIONPROCESSOR_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would you expect a variable that is set _after an instance of the class is constructed_ to be usable _while the class is being loaded_? Not that this will compile in the first place. Just ditch all the static business and make everything instance variables initialized in the constructor.

Comment: You are correct. But this is a client stub created by wsimport for Jax ws. I cannot remove the static block as then I will have to make other overridden methods non-static as well which won't go well with the superclass javax.xml.ws.Service.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible and should not be used..

It is an anti pattern to mix up static context and the context of your Dependency Injection Framework.

Depending on where you want to inject your env it should not make a big difference since Spring will handle your component/service as an Singleton on the Injection Context.

Summary: Don't use a lot of Static Context in your Spring Application

Comment: I agree. But this is a Jaxws client stub generated by wsimport. I just want to change the WSDL file location on runtime depending on the environment.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below tool in static to obtain env variable

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;

@Service
@Lazy(false)
public class SpringContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware, DisposableBean{
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static void clearHolder() {
        applicationContext = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        SpringContextHolder.clearHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringContextHolder.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

how to use

```java
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

//--- pass some code
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

        Environment environment = SpringContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"));
    }

}
```

Comment: This resulted in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. SpringContextHolder.getApplicationContext() is coming as null;

Comment: Invoking static code should after SpringApplication.run(). I modify code sample to show clearly.

Comment: It worked!! I added @Lazy(true) to the class which has a static block and made sure SpringContextHolder gets loaded before it. Thanks a lot.